# How to fix apps with bad WebRTC versions

Tags: android-security, android-securityexception

I am an Android developer.
I released an app for internal public testing and the following error was listed in the pre-release report summary.
"How to fix apps with bad WebRTC versions."
However, I am using WebView and not WebRTC. How do I fix this?

The following is the URL you were guided to at the time of the error.
https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/12577537

The following is build.gradel

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 32
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionName '2.2'
        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
        versionCode 32
        ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        stagingConfig
        productConfig
    }
    flavorDimensions "default"
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    ndkVersion '21.4.7075529'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.1.0'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.0.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.22@aar'
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.1'
}

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral ();
    jcenter()
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            details.useVersion '27.1.0'
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```